# Bluetooth Mouse MX Master in Ubuntu 20.04 - Scrolling became slow after upgrade

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and a Bluetooth Logitech Mouse MX Master 3

Yesterday my mouse was working perfectly but today, using the scroll wheel makes the scrolling in every application extremely slow.

I did a software upgrade yesterday with `sudo apt full-upgrade`, which is the only thing that comes to my mind, that could have messed things up.

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by plugging out and again in the Logitech Unifying Receiver...

Not sure what the issue was, but that solved it.